# How to Send a payload to a firebase OnRequest Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, postman

I have a firebase post function that I am trying to send some data to but the problem I am having is that I the body comes empty. I am using express for the function.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const moment = require("moment");
const cors = require("cors");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
admin.initializeApp();
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json({limit: "10kb"}));

// Mpesa Express
app.post("/express", _accessToken, (req, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify("FELOOOOOO", req.body));
  console.log(JSON.stringify("felix"));

 res.status(200).json(req.body);
 
});

exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The functions run but when I log the req.body it comes empty. I have used postman to send the post request but still, the req.body comes empty despite passing in some data. Kindly help solve the error. below is a screenshot of the postman request
[image]

Comment: Code looks fine, just make sure you have added the `Content-Type` header as a `application/json` in Postman

Comment: @ArifKhan Content-type application/json is on the headers

Comment: What about `req.rawBody`?

Comment: req.rawBody comes empty too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be sending the data correctly but are incorrectly using `JSON.stringify()`. The object is the first argument, not the second. Make it `JSON.stringify(req.body)` - that should work.

You can read up more about the function over at MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I was using JSON.stringify() wrongly.